# Custom implementation of a HashTable in Java?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, hashtable, trove4j

I was solving the [Quora problem](http://www.quora.com/challenges) and for my particular solution I needed a hashtable (long-keys, int-values) for caching values. I hoped that the Java HashMap could be improved because I knew my data types for the keys and values and they were primitives and also my problem space. I decided to naively go ahead implement a simple hashtable using the "array-of-linkedlist" structure (even my linkedList was my own Node class I had implemented). But I noticed that my own naive implementation was about 4x slower than the generic Java HashMap. I also tried to use [Trove's LongToIntMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TLongIntHashMap.html) library to see what they do. Does anyone have any good suggestions to build a custom Long to Int hashtable in Java that significantly outperforms the Java HashMap?

Comment: Did you profile your code and see where it was spending all its time? In the hash function? Appending linked lists? Adding? Querying?

Comment: Remember Knuth's mantra: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  Unless you have - or have reason to suspect - a problem with the standard library implementation, you probably shouldn't worry about it.  At least not "prematurely" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Javolution's [FastMap](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastMap.html). Source code is available [here](http://kenai.com/projects/javolution/sources).

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried to use Trove's LongToIntMap library to see what they do.

Did you try looking at the code to see how they do it?

---

It is not possible to say say for sure what you did wrong in your implementation without looking at the code.  However one possible improvement might be to replace the `LinkedList<Integer>` with a custom "list of integer" type that uses `int[]` to represent the lists.  Depending on your hash table API, you should be able to avoid the cost of representing your values as objects (specifically `Integer`s).  (And as a corollary, you will get better performance and space utilization by NOT implementing an API that has generic types for the key and/or value types.)

For what it is worth, one mistake that could lead to poor performance is neglecting to implement hashtable resizing.  Without resizing, the complexity of `get` and `put` operations on the table will be `O(N)` rather than `O(1)` ... because the hash chain lengths will grow in proportion to the number of hash table entries.

Finally, you need to be clear in your mind whether you are optimizing for performance or space utilization.  The optimal solution will be different ....

Comment: "... will be O(N) rather than O(N) ..." which is still asymptotically faster than, say, O(N), I guess ... :-)

Comment: @Dirk - fixed.  (you knew what I meant ...)